# Pattern matching for characters

Tags: f#

I am trying to write a function that takes the characters `x`, `r`, `c` and returns `r` if `x = c`, or returns `x` if `x != c`. It basically replaces a matching character with another, or returns the original one if not.

I tried implementing this using pattern matching, but it doesn't behave the way i thought it would. My goal is to transform the string "hello" to the string "herro":

```
let swap_id c r x =
    match x with
    | c -> r
    | _ -> x

let swap_id_2 x =
    match x with
    | 'l' -> 'r'
    | _ -> x

// prints "rrrrr"
printfn "%s" ("hello" |> String.map (swap_id 'l' 'r'))

// prints "herro"
printfn "%s" ("hello" |> String.map (swap_id_2))
```

My Intellisense also tells me, that the _ pattern is never matched in my first function.

How are these two different? What am i missing?

---

Note: I know there is a string.replace(..) function. I just wanted to implement my own one to learn something.